# More efficient method to identify sequences within event data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python programming and working on some code which doesn't appear to be very efficient. I'm trying to find particular sequences of events. Events are listed by row, and I've managed to achieve this using IF statements and the iloc/loc function, by looking at subsequent events to establish whether a sequence of interest is discovered and to then validate whether this is within the time threshold to be considered.

Works fine for small datasets, however the actual data set i'm trying to run this against is over 100K rows of data, where this method grinds to a halt. Is there a more effective way to doing this with shorter execution times? Code i'm using is below. Thanks in advance.

```
    data = {'Mode':['1', '1', '1', '1','1','1','2'],'EventType':['A', 'A', 'B', 'A','B','B','A'], 'TimeStamp':['01/01/2018 06:20:00', '01/01/2018 06:33:00', '01/01/2018 06:34:01', '01/01/2018 06:35:59', '01/01/2018 06:36:11', '01/01/2018 06:38:59', '01/01/2018 06:42:12']} 
    df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Mode','EventType','TimeStamp'])
    df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'])
    df['SEQ'] =""

column = df.columns.get_loc("EventType")

#iterate over rows and find sequences of interest

for i in range(0,len(df)-1):
        r =0
        if df.iloc[i,column] =="A":
            if df.iloc[i+1,column] =="B":
                if df.iloc[i+2,column]=="A":
                    df.loc[df.index[i],'SEQ'] = 'ABA'
                    r =i+2
                else:
                    if df.iloc[i+3,column] =="A":
                        df.loc[df.index[i],'SEQ'] = 'ABBA'
                        r =i+3
                    else: 
                        df.loc[df.index[i],'SEQ'] = 'ABBB'
                        r =i+3
            else: 
                df.loc[df.index[i],'SEQ'] = 'AA'
                r =i+1
        else:
            if df.iloc[i+1,column]=="B":
                df.loc[df.index[i],'SEQ'] = 'BB'
                r =i+1
            else:
                df.loc[df.index[i],'SEQ'] = 'B'
        if r!=0:
            Duration = (df.loc[df.index[r],'TimeStamp'] - df.loc[df.index[i],'TimeStamp']).total_seconds()
            df.loc[df.index[i],'Duration (Seconds)'] = Duration

# Add relevant thresholds for identified sequences

thresholds = {'ABA': 180,
           'ABBA': 240,
           'BB': 180,
           'AA': 180,
           'ABBB': 240}

df['Threshold (Seconds)'] = [thresholds.get(x) for x in df['SEQ']]   

# Add column for Valid Sequences
df['Valid Duration']= df['Duration (Seconds)'] < df['Threshold (Seconds)']
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to speed up your script, especially if you are dealing with large dataset, you should try to keep the **access** to your dataFrame to a minimum. Each one of your `df.iloc[something]` basically sends your programm off to fetch the data contained at that location. This procedure takes a relatively long time! So you should try to avoid it and keep your data fetches to a minimum. If you are only retrieving single values of your dataset use `df.at[]` instead of `df.loc[]` or `df.iloc[]`.
As you are dealing with sequences and have to fetch multiple rows at a time, I would recommend to use aggregates. So instead of getting each event type at a time, get all of them at once.
My recommendation to you would be to first build your **Sequence** like this:

```py
for i in range(0, len(df) - 1):
    event = df.iloc[i : i + 4, column].str.cat(sep="")
    if event == "ABBB":
        pass
    elif event == "ABBA":
        pass
    elif event.startswith("ABA"):
        event = "ABA"
    elif event.startswith("AA"):
        event = "AA"
    elif event.startswith("BB"):
        event = "BB"
    else:
        event = ""
    df.at[i, "SEQ"] = event
```

There is basically one read operation `df.iloc[i : i + 4, column]`and one write operation `df.at[i, "SEQ"]` per row, instead of the five in your code. 
when calculating the TimeDiff, use `df.at[]` as you are only getting/setting a single value.

```py
    # replace df.loc with df.at, takes half the time as it retrieves single values
    if r != 0:
        df.at[i, "Duration (Seconds)"] = (
            df.at[r, "TimeStamp"] - df.at[i, "TimeStamp"]
        ).total_seconds()
```

That should speed up your code quite a bit. If you can log the performance I would be interested to see the difference this makes on your dataset.

Comment: Wow @cybot , that makes quite a difference. On a small set of data (20 rows), it is 41% faster. On a very large dataset (500K rows) it ran in 210 secs... I gave up after waiting 15 minutes using my original code.